# Akka http, GET Http().singleRequest is throwing server closed connection unexpectedly

Tags: akka, akka-http

Akka-http version - 10.0.14

Akka version - 2.4.20

**Getting below error while using akka http as a client to send GET request and receive the response body.**

Exception in thread "main" akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$UnexpectedConnectionClosureException: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests

Observation:

1. Same GET call is working through curl command
2. Same client code is working for GET call, 'https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/hub/invalidcall'

Code -

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Client {

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(10.seconds)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
      Http().singleRequest(
        HttpRequest(
          uri = "http://localhost:9090/xstreams/v1/offset/getOffset?appId=local-1543580292487&sourceName=mysql",
          //uri="https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/hub/invalidcall",
          method = HttpMethods.GET
        )
      )

    val entity = Await.result(responseFuture, timeout.duration).entity
    val responseStringF = Unmarshal(entity).to[String]
    val responseString = Await.result(responseStringF, timeout.duration)

    println("\nResult = " + responseString)

    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

Comment: show the curl command line that you assert works

Comment: curl -v  -L 'http://localhost:9090/xstreams/v1/offset/getOffset?appId=local-1543580292487&sourceName=mysql'

Comment: So, you're telling curl to follow HTTP30x redirects with -L - does your code do the same? Reason I ask is because I don't do akka - I don't even recognize the language, other than it looking like some c#/vb hybrid, but I read that akka might not follow redirects. I hence think if you're making an HTTP request and getting a 302, then trying to read its response body there wont be a response body (redirect is header only response). If akka didn't follow the 302 automatically like curl did, you wont get a result -> this could be the difference between your code and the working curl

Comment: Solved the issue, when I used 0.0.0.0 or actual IP address as a host address, the get call is working as expected! Don't know what is wrong with 'localhost'!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, when I used 0.0.0.0 or actual IP address as a host address, the get call is working as expected! Don't know what is wrong with 'localhost'!